# C++: How to generate all possible template instantiations for a fixed set of template types?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, pybind11

I need to do as follows:

I have a function of the form

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void func(string a, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, bool b);
```

But the template types would only ever take on the values of either `int` or `vector<int>` and I need to have all the possible instantiations available at compile time for a python extension via Pybind11. Rather than manually writing out each combination (e.g. `func<int,int,vec>`, `func<int,vec,int>`, `func<int,vec,vec>`, etc.) I'd like a way to automatically instantiate all possible combinations of these parameters.

I've seen some ways of doing this recursively with variadic template parameters, but I have a fixed number of template parameters that I would like to do this with. Initially, I was hoping that I could apply some sort of recursive instantiation using a variadic template, limiting it to 3 values, and then assigning those template params to the actual template function like so:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void bind_func(py::module& m) {
  m.def("func", &func<T1, T2, T3, T4>);
}

//Recursive function to generate bindings for all combinations of int and
//vector<int> in three slots
template <unsigned int N, typename... Args> struct generateBindings{
  static void generate(py::module &m) {
    generateBindings<N-1, Args..., int>::generate(m);
    generateBindings<N-1, Args..., vector<int>>::generate(m);
  }
};

template <typename... Args>
struct generateBindings<0, Args...> {
  static void generate(py::module &m) {
    bind_func<Args...>(m);
  }
};

...

//instantiate via:
generateBindings<2,int>(m);
generateBindings<2,vector<int>>(m);
```

But as my compiler tells me, this is invalid - is there an efficient way to do this? Ideally, I could find a solution that also extends to N such parameters and avoids hardcoding these signatures. Would appreciate any help as a beginner :)

Comment: I don't follow your example. You show `func` with 3 template parameters and then you instantiate it with 4 in `bind_func`. What exactly do you need to do? Given a function template that has some number of template parameters, call it with all combinations of `int` and `vector<int>`? If so, you could reduce the question to just that without even mentioning Python.

Comment: Do you think something like that monstrosity you suggested is somehow better than eight lines of explicit code, one per permutation? :-)

Comment: "But as my compiler tells me, this is invalid": How so? (what compiler error do you get). Seems to work fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/8afcrh861